# How to create a new folder in AWS S3 bucket using "amazon-s3-php-class" library?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-4

I'm using this [amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class) library to upload file in my S3 storage bucket. and I'm using **putObjectFile()** function to store file in my S3 storage bucket.

```
$this->s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $s3storageBucket, $fileName, $this->s3->ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
```

I need to create **New folder** in my **AWS S3 bucket** . I have searched all functions in "[amazon-s3-php-class](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class)" library, but nothing found related create new folder in S3 bicket.  Can someone suggest me? Is there any way to create "**new folder**" in my S3 storage bucket using above mentioned library or by other php library?

Answer (score 0):

In Amazon S3 there is no such thing as a new folder.

You simply specify the object name and it will create it for you.

In the console you can via the prefixes (what you would see as subfolders) via the content that matches that key format.

For the PHP SDK you do not need to do anything, just specify the object and put the object there.